# jquery plugin select2 result set

Tags: jquery, web-services, autocomplete

i have a problem with select2 plugin.
I use as source an asp.net web service that return this string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"Comuni":[{"Descrizione":"Volta Mantovana (MN)","CodiceISTAT":20070,"text":"Volta Mantovana (MN)","id":1},{"Descrizione":"Voltaggio (AL)","CodiceISTAT":6190,"text":"Voltaggio (AL)","id":2},{"Descrizione":"Voltago Agordino (BL)","CodiceISTAT":25067,"text":"Voltago Agordino (BL)","id":3}]}</string>
```

and in the result function of select2 i have this

```
results: function (data, page) {
    results: $.parseJSON($(data).text())
}
```

but the plugin will not show me any result.

can someone help me?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$.parseJSON($(data).text())` has to be something like:

```
[{'id':dat1,'text':dat1}, {'id':dat2,'text':dat2},...]
```

put a:

```
alert(JSON.stringify($.parseJSON($(data).text())));
```

to see what you have.

`id` and `text` can have different values, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue.
My web service return a json encapsulated in an xml and i didn't see it.
So I've changed to standard json (with id and text properties) and everything is working.